# Using robust regression to detect outliers

Tags: regression, outliers, robust

Rousseeuw and van Zomeren (1990) propose using robust regression to detect multivariate outliers, particularly in OLS regression. This approach seems to make sense (although I have not studied it in detail) but I don't recall seeing this method used.

Is there some problem with it?  Have better methods been found?

Rousseeuw, Peter & C. van Zomeren, Bert. (1990). Unmasking Multivariate Outliers and Leverage Points. Journal of The American Statistical Association - J AMER STATIST ASSN. 85. 633-639. 10.1080/01621459.1990.10474920.

Comment: In a case where any of the relationships in the data are non-linear, such as a sine wave or logarithm, etc., any linear regression - robust or not - would by definition incorrectly classify some data points as outliers.